# event handler in a resources dictionary xaml

Tags: vb.net, xaml, dictionary

i have written this little code in vb.net:

First the main window:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Button Content="Button1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="35,35,0,0" Name="Button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
    <Button Content="Button2" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="35,85,0,0" Name="Button2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
    <StackPanel Name="Display" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Background="LightBlue" Margin="50,150,50,10"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <ContentControl Name="Content">

        </ContentControl>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Then the dictionary:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
x:Class="MyResources">
<Style  TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <EventSetter Event="Button.Click" Handler="Click"/>
</Style>
<DataTemplate x:Key="Template1">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox Margin="10,50,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" />
        <Button Name="BT_1" Content="test1" Margin="10,10" HorizontalAlignment="right" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                Width="150" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="Template2">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox Margin="10,50,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" />
        <Button Name="BT_2" Content="test2" Margin="10,10" HorizontalAlignment="right" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                Width="150" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

And finally the class MyResources which manages the code behind my dictionary:

```
Public Class MyResources
Private Sub Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
    MsgBox("hello")
End Sub
```

End Class

This code compiles properly, no problem. But my problem is this one:

1. First when i am on my mainwindow and i click on button1 or button2, i have a msgbox("hello"). It is a problem because i only want a msgbox when i click on a button in my dictionary, for example BT_1 (the one with content test1).
2. In my dictionary i have added a style and a handler for the buttons of my dictionary. But what i want is to add a specific handler for each button in MyResources class, is it possible?

Typically, i would like to have something like that in MyResources class:

```
Private Sub Click_one(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
    MsgBox("BT_1 clicked")
End Sub

Private Sub Click_two(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
    MsgBox("BT_2 clicked")
End Sub
```

But i can't add handles BT_1...after my methods..

I give you thanks for your answers. Please, don't send me the links where similars threads have been evocated, i have ridden a lot of them and that didn't help me...

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do that, because you can't create dynamically an event handler name in your resource file.
I don't think the XAML syntax can let you do that.

Still need to add your event handlers manually, for each and every button you cant a click event.